# Visual Studio 2015 compiler error C1060

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The following code causes in Visual Studio 2015 fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space.
If I use 64 bit version of compiler It eat more than 25Gb of ram for this sample.
Visual Studio 2012 and 2010 works fine. This is a compiler error?

```
class Test
{
public:

    Test() :
        m_val1(0),
        m_val2(0)
    {
    }

    Test(Test *val1) :
        m_val1(val1),
        m_val2(0)
    {
    }

    Test(Test *val1, Test *val2) :
        m_val1(val1),
        m_val2(val2)
    {
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        if (m_val1)
            delete m_val1;
        if (m_val2)
            delete m_val2;
    }

private:
    Test* m_val1;
    Test* m_val2;
};

int main()
{
    Test t(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(
        new Test(new Test(new Test),
                 new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(),
                                                              new Test()),
                                                     new Test(new Test(),
                                                     new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(new Test(),
                                                                                                                                               new Test())))))))))))
        )))))))))))))));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a compiler problem, but your code is extreamly unusual and nobody would write code like that for real projects.

Comment: Btw, it's safe to delete null pointers; the test is redundant.

Comment: If anyone working with me wrote that sort of code, it wouldn't be the compiler I was questioning ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland It's valuable to know your tools, so I'd appreciate colleagues writing test programs much more than ignorant ones.

Comment: BTW VS2015 with the v120 toolset compiles that code, but with the v140 toolset you get the "out of heap space" error.

Comment: Why on earth would the compiler use so much memory, and heap of all things? (I could envision a stack overflow.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider good question, but I get this error too.

Comment: @Michael Walz This is a very synthetic example. Real code looks not so ugly.

Comment: _MSVC2013 12.0.40629.00 Update 5_ works fine. What version did you test? What update?

Comment: @ZDF the problem comes with VS2015 and the v140 toolset.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, but what update?

Comment: Is it relevant that it's not a completely straight recursion but that it has a few intermediate closing brackets?

Comment: Another thing is that, I think, a compiler would be free to not generate any code at all since the program has no observable behavior, provided `new` doesn't have any. Are there example where a compiler eliminates dynamic allocation of objects which are never accessed?-- For what it's worth, a cygwin x86_64 gcc 4.9.3 compiles it just fine.

Comment: @ZDF Visual Studio update 1 and update 2 RC

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but here's some news: _[March 3, 2016 Today, we are happy to announce the release candidate (RC) of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx)_ **Edit** Sorry, I didn't notice: it looks like you already have this version.

Comment: @zdf I have update 1

Comment: The front-end was significantly rewritten in VS2015.  Technical debt that had to paid, it prevented complete C++1x compliance, its original design dated from an era where the compiler was expected to run on a machine with 256 KB of memory.  The message is a bit misleading, it doesn't actually run out of heap space.  If it would then using the x64 compiler would fix it, it doesn't.  And it shows up too quickly.  Stack space is more likely.  You have a 1-800 support phone number you can call, pretty hard to be taken seriously though when you show them code like this.

Comment: I posted the issue to the Microsoft Connect.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2438722

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. The minimal code is below.

If the number of functions is small enough, the compiler issues two warnings: `main::A a(...prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)` and `'a': unreferenced local variable`; else, on my computer, it hangs.

If you replace the parenthesis with braces, to remove the ambiguity, everything is fine.

```
int main()
{
  class A {};
  A a( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A( A(  ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) );
  // fine: A a{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{ A{} } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } };

  return 0;
}
```